# if statement problem, could you please, explain?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

can someone please explain me what is the problem with my `If` statement ?
My code is

```
if(row < coloredRow || column < coloredColumn) {
  return alert('Error')
} else { 
  //return code
}
```

when I write **5 5 2 2** to the inputs it is ok and work but when I put **10 10 2 2** it triggers the Error alert. Here is the live version in codepen(https://codepen.io/ruslancik/pen/mdPeaYw?editors=1111) just try **5 5 2 2** and later **10 10 2 2**

```
function createTable() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = document.getElementById("row").value;
  var column = document.getElementById("column").value;
  var coloredRow = document.getElementById("rowColor").value;
  var coloredColumn = document.getElementById("columnColor").value;
  if(row < coloredRow || column < coloredColumn) {
    return alert('Error')
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < row; i++) {
      var x = table.insertRow(i);
      for (var j = 0; j < column; j++) {
        var y = x.insertCell(j);
        y.innerHTML = "Row-" + i + " Column-" + j;
      }
    }
    for (var z = 0; z < row; z++) {
      table.rows[coloredRow - 1].style.backgroundColor = "red";
      table.rows[z].cells[coloredColumn - 1].style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      table.rows[coloredRow - 1].cells[coloredColumn - 1].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The `.value` properties are always *strings*, so your comparisons are comparing as strings instead of numbers.

Comment: change all you values to int (e.g. parseInt) `var row = parseInt(document.getElementById("row").value);` so theye compared as Int, not as Strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing strings, not numbers.  And the string `'10'` is indeed "less than" the string `'2'`, because the first character in that string has a lower ASCII value.  (Basically you're ordering them *alphabetically*, not *numerically*.)

Parse your values as numbers:

```
var row = parseInt(document.getElementById("row").value, 10);
// repeat for other values
```

Comment: Thank you David. It helped. I have tried parseInt() inside the for loop before but it did not help me. But this way is great.